# How to put selected items of checkboxes to a String array

Tags: vb.net

Here's what I am trying to do, I want to put all the items checked or selected on checkboxes and put it in an
array of string then show it on a dynamic array of labels by the trigger of a button..
Here's the codes that I have tried so far...

```
Dim arraySize As Integer
Dim lbl() As Label
Dim str() As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.Text = arraySize
End Sub
Private Sub chkOption1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkOption1.CheckedChanged
    If chkOption1.Checked = True Then
        arraySize = arraySize + 1
    Else
        arraySize = arraySize - 1
    End If
    Label1.Text = arraySize
End Sub
Private Sub chkOption2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkOption2.CheckedChanged
    If chkOption2.Checked = True Then
        arraySize = arraySize + 1
    Else
        arraySize = arraySize - 1
    End If
    Label1.Text = arraySize
End Sub
Private Sub chkOption3_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkOption3.CheckedChanged
    If chkOption3.Checked = True Then
        arraySize = arraySize + 1
    Else
        arraySize = arraySize - 1
    End If
    Label1.Text = arraySize
End Sub
Private Sub chkOption4_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkOption4.CheckedChanged
    If chkOption4.Checked = True Then
        arraySize = arraySize + 1
    Else
        arraySize = arraySize - 1
    End If
    Label1.Text = arraySize
End Sub
Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    ReDim lbl2(arraySize)
    ReDim str(arraySize)
    For ctr = 1 To lbl2.Length - 1
        lbl(ctr) = New Label
        lbl(ctr).Width = 60
        lbl(ctr).Height = 40
        If ctr = 1 Then
            lbl(ctr).Left = 20
        Else
            lbl(ctr).Left = ((lbl2(ctr).Width + 20) * ctr) - 60
        End If
        lbl(ctr).Top = Me.Height - lbl(ctr).Height * (5 / 2)
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl(ctr))
    Next
    For ctrs = 1 To gn.Length - 1
        If chkAction.Checked = True Then
            str(ctrs) = "Action"
        End If
        If chkFantasy.Checked = True Then
            str(ctrs) = "Fantasy"
        End If
        If chkMystery.Checked = True Then
            str(ctrs) = "Mystery"
        End If
        If chkWar.Checked = True Then
            str(ctrs) = "War"
        End If
        lbl(ctrs).Text = str(ctrs)
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is, when I choose or check one or more checkboxes, the one that
is shown in labels is always the last checkbox according to its order.. For example I checked chkOption1, chkOption3,
chkOption2, the output on labels are all "chkOption3". And if I checked an item and press the button one at a time it will
show the right value that I want in labels. But what I am trying to do is if I select one or more
checkboxes it will show all the values in labels by just a single click in a button, for example I choose option1, option4, option3, option2, then it will
show all the values option1 to 4 in labels... So how can I do this?? Please help. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `List(Of T)` and a `For Each`

The principle here is to check every control of type `CheckBox` and retrieve its value and add it to a list.

> Be careful this will not work if the checkbox are inside a `GroupBox`
>   or other container. If that's the case then you need to loop through
>   all the controls of the container.

```
Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    Label1.Text = ""
    Dim SelectedGenres As List(Of String)
    SelectedGenres = GetGenres()
    For Each Genre As String In SelectedGenres
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text & vbNewLine & Genre
    Next
End Sub
```

And then would use a function like this:

```
Public Function GetGenres() As List(Of String)
    Dim Genres As New List(Of String)
    Genres.Clear()
    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        'If the control is of type Checkbox
        Dim CurrentCheckbox As CheckBox
        If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
            CurrentCheckbox = ctrl
            If CurrentCheckbox.Checked = True Then
                Genres.Add(CurrentCheckbox.Text)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return Genres
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest you use a list instead of an array, especially since the size varies. You don't need to keep the size of the array. Just use an List(Of String)

```
Dim selectedActions As New List(Of String)

If chkAction.Checked Then selectedActions.Add("Action")
If chkFantasy.Checked Then selectedActions.Add("Fantasy")
If chkMystery.Checked Then selectedActions.Add("Mystery")
If chkWar.Checked Then selectedActions.Add("War")
```

Then you got your arraySize

```
selectedAction.Count
```

Just loop that list to get the information

```
For ctr = 0 To selectedActions.Count-1
    Dim lbl As New Label
    lbl.Width = 60
    lbl.Height = 40
    If ctr = 1 Then
        lbl.Left = 20
    Else
        lbl.Left = ((lbl2(ctr).Width + 20) * ctr) - 60
    End If
    lbl.Top = Me.Height - lbl.Height * (5 / 2)
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)

    lbl.Text = selectedActions(ctrs)
Next
```

If the max number of values are fixed. It could be easier for you to just add empty labels and hide/show or set the .Text to "" if there's no value. In your code, you will create new labels every time.

Comment: I thought of doing this at first but then i went with the dynamic approach because maybe there's a lot of checkbox and it could be annoying to hardcode every if

Comment: @Mederic that is a good point. When you get it working, you could look at using grids (depending on how you want your UI to work).

Comment: I didn't ask the question I actually answered with the dynamic aproach lol